# How to slice find result with php and mongo?

Tags: php, mongodb

I am doing a website with php and mongo. I want to display a list of contacts, with 15 contacts by page, and add a [next] / [previous] link at the bottom of the page. So I need to slice the results returned by my [find] operator. I spent 2 hours now looking at documentation, without finding the way to do it, mainly because I do not project on any field : I just want all the fields, and to have value from 1 to 15 and then 16 to 30, etc... How to do that ??

I tried something like that, but it does"t work :

```
$cursor = $contacts->find(array(), array( '$slice' => [1, 15] ) );
```

Comment: maybe should I look at cursor->skip(n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplest/minimal example of pagination. I am showing you only the code you are struggling with. This is not a complete working pagination code. Rest of it you can write yourself I guess.

```
$skip_results = (int)($results_per_page * ($page_number - 1));
$cursor = $collection->find($query)->limit($results_per_page)->skip($skip_results);
```

Then you can loop through `$cursor` and do whatever you want. Hope this is good enough take to in right direction.